# move_uploaded_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in

Tags: php

```
<?php

include("mysqlconnect.php");

function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
{
    if(empty($imagetype)) return false;

    switch($imagetype)
    {
        case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
        case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
        case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
        case 'image/png': return '.png';
        default: return false;
     }
}



if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "img/".$imagename;


    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name)) {

        $query_upload="INSERT INTO test_image ('id' ,'image', 'image_path',     'submission_date') VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";

        mysqli_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysqli_error());  

    }else{

        exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    } 

}

?>
```

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/u957762221/public_html/saveimage.php on line 29

This code throws an Error when attempting to upload an image to the server

Comment: I have provided with a solution. Implement it and share thoughts if you find any hinderance.

Comment: You have been missing the connection variable in the `mysqli_query()`. I have figured out the error. Hope so it helps you ..

Comment: just [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[move_uploaded_file(string $filename, string $destination)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

This function needs second parameter as destination (where to upload file). You just gave one parameter (`$temp_name`, which is file name). I see something similar to destination in your code, so try this instead:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

> First, you may not really need that `GetImageExtension()` Function. PHP's `pathinfo()` would do just fine in getting the Extension for You. 
>   Anyways; below would be the right syntax for `move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination)`, which accepts 2 parameters: 1st the File-Name (from the $_FILES Global) and the Destination (The Path to where you wish to save the File - including File-Name, though.

```
<?php

    include("mysqlconnect.php");


    if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) { 
        $file_name      = $_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
        $temp_name      = $_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
        $imgtype        = $_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
        $ext            = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
        $imagename      = date("d-m-Y") . "-" . time() . "." . $ext;
        $target_path    = "img/".$imagename;

        // YOU JUST FORGOT THE DESTINATION: $target_path ;-)
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {  
            // HERE WE USED THE IMAGE-TYPE/EXT. AS THE VALUE FOR THE TABLE-COLUMN: `image`
            // IT IS UP TO YOU TO SUBSTITUTE THE RIGHT VALUES THERE...  
            $query_upload   = "INSERT INTO test_image ('image', 'image_path', 'submission_date') VALUES ";
            $query_upload  .= "('" . $ext . "', " . $target_path . "', '".date("Y-m-d")."' )";


            mysqli_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysqli_error());

        }else{      
            exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you but I still have an error ><

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/u957762221/public_html/saveimage.php on line 17

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/u957762221/public_html/saveimage.php on line 17
error in INSERT INTO test_image ('id' ,'image', 'image_path', 'submission_date') VALUES ('img/25-09-2016-1474813786png','2016-09-25') == ---->

Comment: The `mysqli_query` requires the db connection as the first argument - so more like `mysqli_query( $con, $query_upload );` and if `id` is an auto-increment column ( which is quite usual ) then the sql statement would not need that - besides there are fewer values passed than are required. Also, the column names should be surrounded by backticks rather than single quotes

Comment: @Nutcha Waropashpimarn      That, now is a new issue.... A MySQL-Based issue but the post has been updated to address that as well..... check it out...

Answer (score 1):

> It is mandatory to pass two arguments for the move_upload_file() other wise it will be pointing out the error while upload.

Arg:1 `file` - Required. Specifies the file to be moved

Arg:2 `newloc` - Required. Specifies the new location for the file

**move_uploaded_file()** - This will upload the file to the server where we point out in the target path so that the retrieval of the images are found to be easy and the images display is done with the help of the uploaded pictures alone.

The move_uploaded_file() function moves an uploaded file to a new location.

This function returns TRUE on success, or FALSE on failure.

Syntax: `move_uploaded_file($filename, $filepath);`

Where

```
$filename: $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

$filepath:  is the folder where you need to upload the images.
```

> mysqli_query($conn,$query_upload) - It needs two parameters one is the connection variable and the other one is to process with the query.

Here

```
$conn- Connection variable for the DB
$query_upload - It is the query to be executed.
```

Replace your code with the below one.

```
<?php
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$target_path)) {

$query_upload="INSERT INTO test_image ('image', 'image_path', 'submission_date') VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";

mysqli_query($conn,$query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysqli_error());  

}else{

   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: @Nutcha Waropashpimarn . Try using this code. And share thought on that.